# How to share Login Info or shared data in Multiple XAP files for a silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, xap

I have a silverlight application with Mulitiple XAP for each Module, I want to share Login Info to each XAP in the application.

Please help.

Comment: What type of authentication does your application use?